# NetSuite Formula Percentage and Case When

Tags: if-statement, case, netsuite

```
Field            Summary Type   Formula
Customer         Group                      
Formula (Text)   Group          CASE {custrecord1} WHEN '15' THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END
Customer ID      Count
```

The above results group the customers and provide a count of A vs B customer records. Is there a way to return the percentage of A vs B records (customer ID count) for each customer instead of showing it as a percentage of Total by using the formula (percentage) function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Field: Formula(Percentage)
Summary Type: Average
SUM(CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = '15' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/SUM(CASE WHEN {custrecord1} != '15' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```